# How can I close a child window without closing the parent?

Tags: c++, winapi, window

I have a window which has 5 child windows. How can I close a child window without closing the parent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably you have handles for the child windows? If so, then just use [`DestroyWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682.aspx).

EDIT:

You should define a WndProc method in your main 'window' to handle callbacks from your child windows. You use this to define what you want to do with each message. In your case, you want to call destroyWindow.

Something like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When i click "close window" (on child window) i sent a message "WM_CLOSE" how i can filter him?

Comment: Don't send `WM_CLOSE`. Call `DestroyWindow`. You are using the child window handle rather than the parent window handle I presume.

Comment: Oh okey, but now i have a new problem. Example, i create a 4 child window and when i close 3rd closes and 4th.. and if i close 2nd closes 3rd and 4th and etc. Why?

Comment: At a guess, your 4 windows aren't all children of the same parent. 4 is a child of 3 which is a child of 2 which is a child of 1. If you kill 2, then 3 and 4 must also die..

Comment: im create a massiv of hWnd.
hWndChild[q] = CreateWindow ( 
   ..
            hWnd,                
...
);           
Its wrong? hWnd - my parent Window

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me.  I had added a case `WM_DESTROY` to the window procedure I registered for my child windows.  This was causing my entire application to quit.  Once removed, everything worked good.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I did this to solve it:

1. Create a global handle variable the will be used as a reference to the main parent window.

   ```
   HWND mainHwnd;
   ```
2. In the main function of the program where the parent window is first created I did this:

   ```
   mainHwnd = CreateWindowEx( /* your window setup here */ );
   ```
3. Then, in the LRESULT method I did this:

   ```
   LRESULT CALLBACK AboutWindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){

       switch(msg){

       case WM_COMMAND:{
           switch(wParam){

           case BTN_ABOUT_CLOSE:
               EnableWindow(mainHwnd, true); // => THIS IS THE SOLUTION
               DestroyWindow(hWnd);
               break;

           }
           break;
       }

       case WM_CREATE:{
           // WHATEVER HAPPENS HERE...
           break;
       }

       case WM_CLOSE:{
           EnableWindow(mainHwnd, true); // => AND HERE TOO, IN CASE USER CLOSES THE WINDOW USING THE X BUTTON
           DestroyWindow(hWnd);
           break;
       }
       default:{
           return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
       }
   }

   return 0;

   }
   ```

I hope it helps. Happy coding!